# UITextField Not Allowing Input

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am programatically adding a `UITextField` into a `UIImageView`. When I set the text property, I can see the text.

The issue is, it's not letting me input text into it like an input field when I run the app.

This is my code for initializing the TextField:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(38.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width - 38.0f, 40.0f);
textField.text = @"Hello";
textField.background = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"field.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:19];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[bar addSubview: textField];
```

Do I need to do something special to allow for text input?

Comment: I think you should addSubview for the parent UIView not the UIImageView. Or try to set bar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: There we go-- setting bar.userInteractionEnabled worked. If you want to post that as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: is there a reason that u sud addSubview to UIImageView?

Comment: I suppose I could use a UIView and a background image... No real reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bar is an `UIImageView`, try to set

```
bar.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Text Field not added into imageview . You can add textfield on view,for user interaction enabled.
First you can add imageview and then add text field on the view.

Like This--

`[self.view addSubview:imgV];
    [self.view addSubview: textField];`